# Make read more button display text smoothly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, button, transition

I'm trying to figure out how I can make the read more button display the text smoothly or slowly like a slow animation or transition with JavaScript  instead of the instant text display.

The source code was from w3schools read more button tutorial.

I'd really appreciate any assistance.

```
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet.</span></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");

  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");

  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {

    dots.style.display = "inline";

    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";

    moreText.style.display = "none";

  } else {

    dots.style.display = "none";

    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";

    moreText.style.display = "inline";

  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SEE NEW RESPONSE BELOW**

Original answer:

You can achieve this with CSS much more easily, using the `transition` property.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

add the css transition property to the base state (not hover state) of any object that you'd like to have a stylized transition when changing to a hover (or other) state. Remember you always have to define the property of the object in its base state to change it in the hover state. For example, if you want to change text from black to pink on hover, you can't just let the text inherit the `color: black;` property from the parent object, you have to define the color of the object in order to then change it in the `object:hover{}` state.

`transition` is the shorthand version of `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`, and `transition-delay`, in that order.

You can also do the exact same things with javascript, but it is actually more complex to do because animating javascript functions can be finicky. That being said, you can do more *complex* animations with javascript, but I don't think it's worth the payout (this is a personal preference. The javascript will, eventually and with enough code, slow down your load time, and for a button I just don't think it's worth it).

```css
body {
    background: #253e4c;
}
div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 15vh auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15vh 10vw;
    display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
button {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #13d7e5;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

span {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #008095;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #13d7e5;
    border: 5px solid #008095;

}
button:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>
    <span>Hello</span>
</button>
</div>
```

---

so... you can achieve this with transitions in css... but i don't remember how... here's some javascript lol

```js
function hello() {
const hidden = [{
    opacity: '1'
  },
  {
    opacity: '0'
  }
];
const shown = [{
    opacity: '0'
  },
  {opacity: '1'}
];

const appearTiming = {
  duration: 200,
  iterations: 1,
}

var button = document.getElementById('button')
var appear = document.getElementById('appear');
if (window.getComputedStyle(appear, null).opacity == "1") {
    appear.animate(hidden, appearTiming);
    appear.style.opacity = 0;
  } else {
    appear.animate(shown, appearTiming);
    appear.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #253e4c;
}
div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 15vh auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15vh 10vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
button {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #13d7e5;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

span {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #008095;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #13d7e5;
    border: 5px solid #008095;

}
button:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fff;
}
#appear {
    transition: opacity 1s, display 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button id="button" onclick="hello()">
    <span>Hello</span>
</button>
<p id="appear">This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohhh sorry I mean the text not the button. The moment you click a read more button it instantly displays the underlying text. So I'm asking how I can make it display slowly

Comment: Give me a few seconds, i'll revise my answer! Same principle applies though, you'll want to do a transition with opacity :) @okino75

Comment: @okino75 if this doesn't do what you want it to, ping me again and i'll revise it in the morning. I've got some work to do now though!

Comment: Hello are you less busy?

Comment: @okino75 What's up